# Implementing data structure - flex dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable, skip-lists

I've been asked to devise a data structure that represents a dictionary. The dictionary holds items with distinct key number. The data structure should support the following operations in O(1) time: insert(x), delete(x), findMin(), findMax(), successor(x), predecessor(x). Also search(x) operation should be in O(log n) time.

The assignment was given on the following subjects: skip list, hash tables and heaps. I guess the best structure will be a skip list, but I couldn't find a way implementing insert and delete in O(1) tine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use both hash table and skip list data structures. 
 You can update `min` and `max` values each time you insert an element. Hence,`findMin()` and `findMax()` are also `O(1)`.
`insert()` and `delete()` are also in constant time.

By the way, you cannot delete an item before searching for it. If you do search in `O(logn)`, `delete()` will be `O(logn)` automatically.

Hash table provides (if implemented correctly), search, delete and insert in `O(1)`. The rest of the operations (`successor()`, `predecessor()`) are available in skip list.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it appears I forgot to mention few assumptions: delete(k) operation gives you indicator to the element. Also, there is probability about inserted element: x.key is smaller than at least n-i items with the probability of (2^(i+1)-1)/2^(i+1).

Comment: @user3680924 what you're defining is a hash table.